# Connection between piecewise linear basis functions and RELU activation function

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-programming, machine-learning

ReLU activation is defined as follows
$$\sigma(x)=\max(0, x).$$
Let's assume that I have deep network of 1 hidden layer, than output from my layer has form 
$$ f(x)= \sigma(Wx +b), $$
where matrix W represents the weights, b is bias and x stands for input data (output of previous layer).

What is connection  between $f(x)$ and piecewise linear function, defined as
$$g(x_j)=\sum_{i=N}^N \alpha_i \psi_i(x_j),$$ 
where $\alpha_i$ stands for the coefficients and $\psi_i$ for the basis function.

More precisely, I would like to identify basis functions and coefficients in the definition of $f(x)$.